# Where does the parameter go in a callback?

Tags: javascript

So a basic example of what I am wondering:

First I create an object with a callback, initiated like this.

```
lblogin.loginlightbox ("AddCallback", function(){ // this function is the callback

    // print true on success from callback in second snippet
    // or
    // print false on fail from callback in second snippet

});
```

Then from within the lightbox object the callback is set at self.options.curHandler, where self is a reference to the lightbox.

```
if(success) //arbitrary condition
  self.options.curHandler(true);
else
  self.options.curHandler(false);
```

The callback does work properly and everything, I am just wondering if it is possible to access these true/false values from the first code snippet. I am unable to find out where they go.

Thank you.

Comment: Whoever voted me down, could you please let me know why.

Comment: What true/false values? I don't see any in the first code snippet. Your question is unclear to me. Or did you mean the `success` in the second snippet should be accessed from the first?

Comment: @cookiemonster The true and false values that are passed as parameters to the callback (which is created in the first snippet) from the second code snippet. Where do they go?

Comment: You're manually invoking the callback? How is it related to the anonymous function in the first example? Are they the same?

Comment: I'm going to rework the question to make it more clear, because theres obviously a gap between what im asking and what i want it to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions take parameters in exactly the same way named ones do, but you've declared a function with no parameters as your callback.

The following are all equivalent (as far as this behaviour is concerned):

```
function myCallback(someArg) { console.log(someArg); }
myCallback('hello');

function myCallback(someArg) { console.log(someArg); }
something.test.callback = myCallback;
something.test.callback('hello');

something.test.callback = function(someArg) { console.log(someArg); }
something.test.callback('hello');
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this... but I didn't clear the cache on my browser so it appeared to not be working.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you just have to add a variable to access the arguments passed to your callback method.

```
lblogin.loginlightbox ("AddCallback", function(value){ // this function is the callback
    //You can use the value passed to callback here (boolean in your case)
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it comes back as undefined every time.  Arguments.length is also 0.

Comment: *update scratch that, browser caching is my enemy.  This does work, but is better explained by someone else, you still get an upvote! :D

Answer (score 0):

Given this syntax:

```
var a = 1;
// or this could be an Ajax response handler, or some other asynchronous function
setTimeout(function(){
   a = 2;
   var b = 7;
   alert('something');
},1000);
alert(a);
```

- You will always receive an alert of "1". This is because that inner function is called *after* the alert is called. This means the value of `a` has not yet changed. You may want to look into [asynchronisity](http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101).
- You would not be able to access `b`, because `b` only exists in the inside function. This is something called "variable scoping".
- You cannot access the value of `'something'` because that isn't assigned to a variable at all.